# Using Putty and AWS: How do I upload a server certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, putty

I've been trying to figure out what belongs within each of these fields:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name certificate_object_name --certificate-body file://public_key_certificate_file --private-key file://privatekey.pem --certificate-chain file://certificate_chain_file
```

I have received an email with 6 downloads:

PKCS#7 Base64 encoded

as PKCS#7 Bin encoded

as X509, Base64 encoded

as X509 Certificate only, Base64 encoded

as X509 Intermediates/root only, Base64 encoded

as X509 Intermediates/root only Reverse, Base64 encoded

I am using this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html but I am stuck on the "To upload a server certificate" section.

What exactly is supposed to go in the fields with "??"?

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate 
--server-certificate-name <Server Name> <-- My input
--certificate-body file://<??.pem> 
--private-key file://<KEYNAME.pem> <-- My input
--certificate-chain file://<??> <-- What should the chain file consists of and in what format?
```

Thank you,

Comment: Hello, now I get an error that reads "Error passing parameter '--certificate-body': file does not exist: X509 Certificate only, Base64 encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this installed onto the linux server!
Here is the exact command I inserted into the Putty command line:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name mywebsitecert --certificate-body file:///home/ec2-user/mywebsite/mywebsitecert.pem --private-key file:///home/ec2-user/mywebsite/privatekey.pem --certificate-chain file:///home/ec2-user/mywebsite/interm_reverse.cer
```

I used InCommon SSL Certificates to complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

`--certificate-body` is the X509 Certificate only, Base64 encoded, `--certificate-chain` is the X509 Intermediates/root only, Base64 encoded.